# Jolt specification to transform JSON input into required format

Tags: arrays, json, jolt

I have following input format :

```json
[
  {
    "id": 5417,
    "customer": 2000444,
    "deleted": false,
    "deleted_date": null,
    "photo_url": null,
    "additional_data": {
      "employee_id": "318878",
      "employee_type": "FTE"
    }
  }
]
```

I want to convert into below format :

```json
{
  "GetUserResp": [
    {
      "id": 5417,
      "customer": 2000444,
      "deleted": false,
      "deleted_date": null,
      "photo_url": null,
      "additional_data": {
        "employee_id": "318878",
        "employee_type": "FTE"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you please help me with JOLT specification ?

Answer (score 1):

You just can use an **`@`** wildcard which will replicate the object along with an array wrapper which will have the provided key name such that

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "GetUserResp"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping. Getting the result as expected with this jolt specification.